# Mocking method of generic repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, repository-pattern

I'm trying to mock the following method using Moq:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    ...

    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");

}
```

It's initialized this way:

```
_invoiceRepository = new SqlGenericRepository<InvoiceEntity>(Context);
```

No matter of the parameter, the method should always return a list.

I tried

```
_invoiceRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<>()).Returns(...)
```

and

```
_invoiceRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<InvoiceEntity, bool>>>())).Returns(...)
```

but both didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
var _invoiceRepositoryMock = new Mock<InvoiceEntity>();
```

Then setup can be

```
_invoiceRepositoryMock
    .Setup(m => m.Get(
        It.IsAny<Expression<Func<InvoiceEntity, bool>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<InvoiceEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<InvoiceEntity>>>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(...);
```

or more specific

```
_invoiceRepositoryMock
    .Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<InvoiceEntity, bool>>>(), null, string.Empty))
    .Returns(...);
```

Comment: There's a `)` missing in your "specific call" (before `.Returns`). But it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your method is :

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,    
    string includeProperties = "");
```

Your mock have to be something like :

```
_invoiceRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Get(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<InvoiceEntity, bool>>>(),
    It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<InvoiceEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<InvoiceEntity>>>(),
    It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(...)
```

Comment: TEntity is unknown in this context.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Replace TEntity by InvoiceEntity obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try like this as there are 4 arguments for the method, try giving 4 arguments in the mock also `_invoiceRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<>(),It.IsAny<>(),It.IsAny<>(),It.IsAny<>()).Returns(...`